# How to register existing elements with Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Fairly new to Angular and working inside of an existing code base.

Basically, there's an element that exists within the root document (index.html) that already exists in the html before the Angular library loads. Because of this, the ng-click directive isn't registered.

Is there an easy way that I can pass Angular a reference to the element in question and have it register that as one of its own?

Sample code (obviously missing parts, just to illustrate Angular loads after):

```
<html>
<body ng-app="allMyCookiesApp">
    <a ng-click="giveGeuisACookie()">GIMME</a>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd like to get a cookie when I click GIMME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-app` will bootstrap everything inside it once angular loads. This includes compiling and linking the `ng-click` in your example. So I think the real problem may be elsewhere.

The biggest omission from this example is any controller. I expect you are missing a controller that can place the `giveGeuisACookie` method on the correct scope to be used by `ng-click`. For example

```
angular.module('allMyCookiesApp', [])
  .controller('geuisCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.giveGeuisACookie = function() {
          // Cookie time
      };
   });
```

would define your module for `ng-app` and register a controller for it. This controller will add the `giveGeuisACookie` function to its scope.

```
<html>
    <body ng-app="allMyCookiesApp" ng-controller="geuisCtrl">
        <a ng-click="giveGeuisACookie()">GIMME</a>
        <script src="angular.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

tells angular to use the controller so that ng-click will have access to the correct method.

If this is not the problem it may be worth adding a jsfiddle with a working (or not) example of what you are doing.

Comment: I was able to solve this earlier this evening. Was the controller that was missing.

Comment: Good stuff. Sounds like this can be marked as the long-winded answer? :)